# Epiphany not blocking adverts

Tags: release-loki, epiphany

I have the 'allow advertisements' checkbox unchecked in Epiphany 3.18.5. However, ads are not removed from web content.

-- EDIT --
For example, coming from Chrome with the AdBlock+ extension, the ads at the top of the Youtube homepage aren't blocked, nor are the ads in videos themselves. Neither are ads from AdChoices, for example the one on the right of [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk).

Comment: you should probably be specific about what ads you're seeing and where.

Comment: Can you specify if there are any adverts that are blocked?

Answer (score 3):

Answer pulled from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470040/how-to-customize-or-debug-ad-blocking-on-gnome-web-epiphany-browser

```
Gnome-web blocks ads on the basis of the URI of the element. The blocking is      
done by the UriTester componant (source code). Like Adblock plus, the tester   
loads a list of patterns from a list, and determine if a URI is an ad if it 
matches one of the pattern.


The file $HOME_DIR/.config/epiphany/adblock/filters.list contains the 
locations of the lists to load (one on each line). If this file doesn't 
exists (e.g. first time you run epiphany), it defaults to "https://easylist-
downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt". Gnome-web then download (and 
periodically refresh) the pattern lists, and store them in the same 
directory (with file name like bedc7ed868397c3dcaf6bc40ed9bbf70)

So, in case of troubles, check that you have filters.list, with one line 
pointing to a valid adblock+ filter, and one file with a file name of 32 hex 
chars, containing valid blocking pattern. If the file filters.list exists, 
but is empty, ads won't be filtered at all.


It is also possible to customize the list used by changing the url in 
filter.list (for instance replacing the default list with a localised list 
like https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/liste_fr+easylist.txt).
```